# Is there a way to extract “area” from a column that contains addresses of customers into a new column in R studio?

Tags: r

For e.g column “address”
Contains
“St 15, house no 54, Nashville Town, New York, USA” and multiple such addresses with different Towns for a log of customers.
I want to make a new column that extracts just the different towns from these addresses into a new column.

I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: What is the pattern? How do you know the town?

Comment: Text parsing is entirely dependent on the _precise_ format of your data, and a single example is not enough to allow us to generalise. Please include a reasonable chunk of examples in text format. Thanks.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit("St 15, house no 54, Nashville Town, New York, USA", ","), \`[[\`, 3)` returns `" Nashville Town"` in this sample. It works here, and will most likely work a some others. It will also likely _fail_ with some others. Address-parsing is full of corner-cases and fraught with peril. How much work you want to put into it depends on how much data you have, whether it's static or you get more frequently, and how confident you are about certain aspects of the strings. I look forward to seeing a larger sample set and description of the whole problem-set.